# Can I use a variable as a column in a select statement?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to select a variable from my stored procedure so that I could get the variable value if I use `ExecuteScalar` in ADO.net.

My stored procedure is this

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SPListGetID
    (
      @category varchar(100)
    )
    AS
      declare @maxListId int
      set @maxListId=(select max(MaterialId) from tblMaterialLists 
                      where category =@category and mode='1')
      set @maxListId=@maxListId+1;
      select @maxListId
      /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
      RETURN
```

Here `select @maxListId` is not allowed. What should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the syntax a bit

```
select @maxListId= max(MaterialId) where category =@category and mode='1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `SET @maxListId=@maxListId+1;` instead of `@maxListId=@maxListId+1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try

`RETURN @maxListId` instead of

```
select @maxListId
      /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
      RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SPListGetID
    (
      @category varchar(100)
    )
    AS
begin
      declare @maxListId int
      select  @maxListId= max(MaterialId) from tblMaterialLists 
                      where category =@category and mode='1'
      set @maxListId=@maxListId+1;

     end
```